# PHP PDO bindValue() without Explicit Data Type

Tags: php, oop, pdo, bindvalue

I am working on an application using PHP object oriented with PDO. I have been struggling for hours finding the problem of why my query execution failed. It turned out that I have supplied a value as parameter in String format to be binded in an array. I have a general loop that binds all of the parameters to the question mark placeholder for my query. That of course will consider the parameters are all in String format. However I have columns in integer format. Even when I cast the variable to integer using `(int)` or `intval()`, it did not work. So I believe I have to specify the explicit data type to `PDO::PDO_PARAM_INT` . But I have code something like this for all queries:

Example of query:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO users (name, numberOfCar") VALUES (?,?) ,
                  array('Jake', 5));
```

The bindValue() part:

```
$x = 1;
if( count($params) ){
    foreach($params as $param){
        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
        $x++;
    }
}
```

How do I go with this? I mean any idea how can I modify the code to catter this issue? Not sure whether I have to modify which part of code but I am puzzled to think the workaround of this. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: PHP version 5.3.10, PDO connect to Sybase

Comment: I just throw it here without testing, but this should work: `$query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (name, numberOfCar") VALUES (:values)")`, then `$query->execute(array('values' => array('Jake', 5)));`

Comment: I cannot use this kind of solution as there are some columns that have a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the problem using php 5.6.3, mysql5.6, win32

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'localonly', 'localonly');  
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
setup($pdo);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO soFoo_users (name, numberOfCar) VALUES (?,?)");
foreach( array('Jake', 5) as $i=>$v) {
    $stmt->bindValue($i+1,  $v);
}
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = null;

foreach($pdo->query('SELECT * FROM soFoo_users', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $r ) {
    echo join(', ', $r), "\r\n";
}

function setup($pdo) {
    $pdo->exec('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo_users (
            name varchar(32),
            numberOfCar int
        )
    ');
}
```

prints

```
Jake, 5
```

as expected

Comment: sorry for late reply. I don't try your proposed solution as yet. But I am beginning to believe it is related to version (could it be?). Because I remember that last time I was having this problem as well on the same server. My PHP version is 5.3.10 and I am using PDO to connect to Sybase database.

Comment: Yes, could be a version problem and/or a driver problem. By default I use a toy mysql server for demos and with little effort could switch to oci or sqlserver  ...but sybase? Which pdo driver do you use? DBLIB, ODBC, ...?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I still need to supply the explicit data type. So I come up with my own solution. Here is how I did it:

```
$this->db->query("INSERT INTO users (name, numberOfCar") VALUES (?,?) ,
              array('Jake', 5),
              array(PDO::PARAM_STR, PDO::PARAM_INT));
```

For value binding:

```
$x = 1;
if( count($params) ){
    foreach($params as $param){
        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param, $datatypes[$x-1]);
        $x++;
    }
}
```

I hope this could help somebody out there if anybody has this kind of problem. Thank you so much to those who helped me on this.